# npm browser-sync with wamp is not working

Tags: php, node.js, codeigniter, wamp, browser-sync

I am developing a Codeigniter project using Sublime Text 3 as editor and wamp as a local server - OS Windows 10. It all works fine but I want to find a way to get the browser to refresh when I save a file. I installed BrowserRefresh in ST3 but it doesn't work. I suspect his might be because it is designed for html files rather than the Codeigniter php structure and inbuilt security. So I installed npm browser-sync (successfully). When I cd to the project folder and start browser-sync using the following in the command line:

```
browser-sync start --server --files "index.php"
```

I get the right response:

```
[Browsersync] Access URLs:
 --------------------------------------
       Local: http://localhost:3001
    External: http://192.168.1.121:3001
 --------------------------------------
          UI: http://localhost:3002
 UI External: http://192.168.1.121:3002
 --------------------------------------
[Browsersync] Serving files from: ./
[Browsersync] Watching files...
```

but in the browser at localhost:3001 I see the response

```
Cannot GET /
```

I'm not an experienced command line user and clearly doing something wrong. I have read something about gulp.js while researching but I know nothing about this and everything I read was completely inexplicable. If I need to use it I will need a step by step tutorial and would welcome any advice.

Comment: ST3 has a plugin you might look at https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Browser%20Refresh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your interest Brad but, as I said in the post, I tried BrowserRefresh and it didn't work. However, I've just come across LiveReload which I'm happy to say works perfectly